# Where are events registered with aura:registerEvent documented in the component spec?

Tags: aura, lightning-events, documentation

This is a seemingly simple question that maybe someone can help me with: the <aura:registerEvent /> tag has a "description" attribute. Based on the way other tags are documented (e.g. <aura:attribute />, <aura:method />, etc.), I would expect the text from the description field to show up in the component documentation when you view your org's component library - specifically in the "Specification" tab, where attributes and methods and their descriptions are shown.

However, registered events don't seem to show up here. Which begs the question, where is the description text ever displayed, if not here? And if the event is not documented in the component specification, how will consumers of the component know there's an event they can handle? Sure, you can put a note about it in the "Documentation" tab, but it stands to reason that it *should* be documented in the specification section as well.

Can anyone provide any insight on this? Am I missing something perhaps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, they appear in the Aura Documentation ( [prod](https://login.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app) | [sandbox](https://test.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app) ). They will appear as "Events" in the Overview tab for the component. I don't know when/if we'll get something like this in the new Component Library.

[image: Sample screenshot of description]

Comment: That's crazy, though, no? I mean, events are an essential part of the component documentation. I'm at a loss for how this didn't make it into the first draft. It's a great documentation tool, but this really almost negates its value if you can't count on the documentation being complete. Anyway, thank you for the tip @sfdcfox, I didnt know about the Aura docs. Interestingly enough, it only seems to show events for components in the same namespace, managed package events, even if global, do not seem to show up here! (which is the use case I have, so looks like I'm out of luck on all fronts) :-/

Comment: @no_stack_dub_sack Also check the Dependencies tab? I forgot to mention that, but it shows relationships to other components, events, etc.

Comment: that seems to be the one saving grace -- I did notice that when browsing around. Even with managed package components, the events are shown here, but their names aren't specified, so still sort of weak. I'll just have to build the events into the documentation tab. Thanks again for your answer.